# TypeError at /careers/test/ jobpost_detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I installed the app careers mezanine and after creating a test position and turn the page to see the error TypeError at / careers / test /
jobpost_detail () got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'. How do I fix this problem?

views

```
from calendar import month_name
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from collections import defaultdict
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django import VERSION

from careers.models import JobPost
from mezzanine.conf import settings
from mezzanine.generic.models import AssignedKeyword, Keyword
from mezzanine.utils.views import render, paginate


def jobpost_list(request, tag=None, year=None, month=None, template="careers/jobpost_list.html"):
    """
    Display a list of job posts that are filtered by year, month.
    """
    settings.use_editable()
    templates = []
    jobposts = JobPost.objects.published()
    if tag is not None:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Keyword, slug=tag)
        jobposts = jobposts.filter(keywords__in=tag.assignments.all())
    if year is not None:
        jobposts = jobposts.filter(publish_date__year=year)
        if month is not None:
            jobposts = jobposts.filter(publish_date__month=month)
            month = month_name[int(month)]
    # We want to iterate keywords and categories for each blog post
    # without triggering "num posts x 2" queries.
    #
    # For Django 1.3 we create dicts mapping blog post IDs to lists of
    # categories and keywords, and assign these to attributes on each
    # blog post. The Blog model then uses accessor methods to retrieve
    # these attributes when assigned, which will fall back to the real
    # related managers for Django 1.4 and higher, which will already
    # have their data retrieved via prefetch_related.

    jobposts = jobposts.select_related("user")
    if VERSION >= (1, 4):
        jobposts = jobposts.prefetch_related("keywords__keyword")
    else:
        if jobposts:
            ids = ",".join([str(p.id) for p in jobposts])
        keywords = defaultdict(list)
        jobpost_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="careers", model="jobpost")
        assigned = AssignedKeyword.objects.filter(jobpost__in=jobposts, content_type=jobpost_type).select_related("keyword")
        for a in assigned:
            keywords[a.object_pk].append(a.keyword)
        for i, post in enumerate(jobposts):
            setattr(jobposts[i], "_keywords", keywords[post.id])
    jobposts = paginate(jobposts, request.GET.get("page", 1),
                          settings.CAREERS_PER_PAGE,
                          settings.MAX_PAGING_LINKS)
    context = {"jobposts": jobposts, "year": year, "month": month, "tag": tag}
    templates.append(template)
    return render(request, templates, context)


def jobpost_detail(request, template="careers/jobpost_detail.html"):
    """. Custom templates are checked for using the name
    ``careers/jobpost_detail_XXX.html`` where ``XXX`` is the job
    posts's slug.
    """
    jobposts = JobPost.objects.published()
    jobpost = get_object_or_404(jobposts)
    context = {"jobpost": jobpost, "editable_obj": jobpost}
    templates = [u"careers/jobpost_detail_%s.html" %(slug), template]
    return render(request, templates, context)
```

html

```
{% extends "careers/jobpost_list.html" %}
{% load mezzanine_tags keyword_tags i18n %}

{% block meta_title %}{{ jobpost.meta_title }}{% endblock %}

{% block meta_keywords %}{% metablock %}
{% keywords_for jobpost as tags %}
{% for tag in tags %}{% if not forloop.first %}, {% endif %}{{ tag }}{% endfor %}
{% endmetablock %}{% endblock %}

{% block meta_description %}{% metablock %}
{{ jobpost.description }}
{% endmetablock %}{% endblock %}

{% block title %}
{% editable jobpost.title %}{{ jobpost.title }}{% endeditable %}
{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumb_menu %}
{{ block.super }}
<li class="active">{{ jobpost.title }}</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<h6>
    {% trans "Posted" %} {{ jobpost.publish_date|timesince }} {% trans "ago" %}.
</h6>

{% editable jobpost.content %}
{{ jobpost.content|richtext_filter|safe }}
{% endeditable %}

{% keywords_for jobpost as tags %}
{% if tags %}
{% spaceless %}
<ul class="unstyled tags">
    <li>{% trans "Tags" %}:</li>
    {% for tag in tags %}
    <li><a href="{% url "jobpost_list_tag" tag.slug %}">{{ tag }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endif %}


{% set_short_url_for jobpost %}
<a class="btn small primary share-twitter" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/home?status={{ jobpost.short_url|urlencode }}%20{{ jobpost.title|urlencode }}">{% trans "Share on Twitter" %}</a>
<a class="btn small primary share-facebook" target="_blank" href="http://facebook.com/sharer.php?u={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}&amp;t={{ jobpost.title|urlencode }}">{% trans "Share on Facebook" %}</a>

{% endblock %}
```

url

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

# Job Post patterns.
urlpatterns = patterns("careers.views",

    url("^tag/(?P<tag>.*)/$",
        "jobpost_list",
        name="jobpost_list_tag"),

    url("^archive/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})/$",
        "jobpost_list",
        name="jobpost_list_month"),

    url("^archive/(?P<year>.*)/$",
        "jobpost_list",
        name="jobpost_list_year"),

    url("^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})/(?P<day>\d{1,2})/(?P<slug>.*)/$",
        "jobpost_detail",
        name="jobpost_detail_date"),

    url("^(?P<slug>.*)/$",
        "jobpost_detail",
        name="jobpost_detail"),

    url("^$",
        "jobpost_list",
        name="jobpost_list"),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you exactly what is going on: your "jobpost_detail" URL the captures a `slug` parameter and passes it on to the view, but that view does not expect a slug, only the request and a template. Also, you are not doing anything in that view to get the actual post identified by a slug: you are always getting the first published post.

I suspect you want to do the following:

```
def jobpost_detail(request, slug, template="careers/jobpost_detail.html"):
    jobposts = JobPost.objects.published()
    jobpost = get_object_or_404(jobposts, slug=slug)
```

Comment: Now error
TemplateSyntaxError in / Career / Test /
Unable to parse the rest : '' 'jobpost_list_tag from ' '' jobpost_list_tag

Comment: Well that appears to be an error in a template you haven't posted.

Comment: Roserman It shows that there is an error <li><a href="{% url 'jobpost_list_tag' tag.slug %}">{{ tag }}</a></li>

Comment: I figured out , but now he writes  NameError at /careers/test/
global name 'Career' is not defined

Comment: Again, that is in some code which you have not posted, where you are referencing the Career model without importing it.

Comment: Django recalls C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\careers\templatetags\career_tags.py" in jobpost_recent_posts
  35.     return list(Career.objects.published()[:limit])

Exception Type: NameError at /careers/test/
Exception Value: global name 'Career' is not defined

file

@register.as_tag
def jobpost_recent_posts(limit=5):
    """
    Put a list of recently published jobpost into the template context.
    """
    return list(Career.objects.published()[:limit])

Comment: Sigh. And did you import Career in that file?